# My loop not calling my function

Tags: function, loops, python-2.7, while-loop, infinite-loop

I am new programming in Python. I am trying to create a function that simply takes the lowest payment (which starts at 10) and it simply returns the remaining balance (after 12 months of payments).

Outside the function I am using a loop that calls the function and checks if the remaining balance is zero or less than zero. If it is not, increment the lowest payment +$10 and call the function again. When remaining balance is zero or less than zero print out the lowest payment.

In theory the output should be as follows :

Test Case 1:

```
balance = 3329
annualInterestRate = 0.2

Result Your Code Should Generate:

******Lowest Payment: 310******

Test Case 2:

balance = 4773
annualInterestRate = 0.2
Result Your Code Should Generate:
```

**Lowest Payment: 440****

```
Test Case 3:

balance = 3926
annualInterestRate = 0.2
Result Your Code Should Generate:
```

**Lowest Payment: 360****

So far, this is what I have :

```
balance = 100
annualInterestRate = 0.2
per_month = ( annualInterestRate / 12 ) 

# Answer is 0.0166666 but I need it to be 0.01, so figured out to convert to string then to float, not the most elegant , but practical. :)

convert_to_str = str(per_month)[:4]
per_month = float(convert_to_str)
lowest_payment = 0

def main():
    i = 0
    while i < 11:
        global balance
        global lowest_payment
        global per_month
        balance = balance - lowest_payment
        balance = ((balance * per_month) + balance)
        i = i +1
        #print (balance)
main()

if balance <= 0 or balance == 0:
    print "Lowest Payment: " + str(lowest_payment)
else:
    lowest_payment = lowest_payment + 10
    main()
```

The problem is that is is not executing my function, and go over the loop again. I have tried with if and while loops. Below my while loop, giving an infinite loop :

```
while balance >= 0 or balance != 0:
    lowest_payment = lowest_payment + 10
    main()
    if balance <= 0:
        print "Lowest Payment: " + str(lowest_payment)
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: In theory, 

    balance = 3329
    annualInterestRate = 0.2

    The Code should Generate:

    Lowest Payment: 310

    Test Case 2:

    balance = 4773
    annualInterestRate = 0.2

    Should Generate :

    Lowest Payment: 440

    Test Case 3:

    balance = 3926
    annualInterestRate = 0.2

   Lowest Payment: 360

Comment: Are you sure the formulas are you using are correct?

Comment: If you are talking about the output, yes, I am sure that is the output it should produce. As for the formulas, I first used an excel spreadsheet to understand the logic, then translate it to code. One of the issues I encountered is when dividing 0.2 / 12, it should give 0.01666666 and only two decimals are allowed. I tried with round(), but it rounded up to the next number, also '%.2f', but same results. I figured out, converting to String then to float should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I found it ... 
You made me think about the formulas .. and got it sorted out. Passed all 12 cases. Below my final code.

```
balance = 100
annualInterestRate = 0.2
month_payment = 10
month_interest = annualInterestRate/12

def debt(balance,month_payment,month_interest):
    for i in xrange(12):
        balance = (balance - month_payment)+month_interest*(balance - month_payment)
    return balance

final_bal = 0
i = 0
while final_bal >=0:
    final_bal = debt(balance,month_payment*i,month_interest)
    month_pay = i*month_payment
    i += 1
print 'Lowest Payment: '+str(month_pay)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
while balance > 0:    
    lowest_payment = lowest_payment + 10
    main()
print "Lowest Payment: " + str(lowest_payment)
```

You may want to modify it as your problem requires.

Comment: Thank You !! Applying the changes that you suggested, it sees and interacts with the function, but what is wrong with my logic ? Let's take the below as an example:

Balance = 3329 .... annualInterestRate = 0.02 , in theory it should give me " Lowest Minimum Payment : 310 " , instead of 110 ( that is what it's printing now ).

Comment: Yes, that's what make me think about a possible mistake in your formulas. By the way, are you sure the `while i < 11`is correct? It shouldn't be ` i < 12`?

Comment: When I was debugging, i was using print statements to see balance, and when I used 12, it was giving -15.2581, that's why I started using 11. But now, I changed it and still giving me 10. If we use 100, it gives me lowest amount : 10, which is correct, but when I go for the Test cases, they are way off .....

Comment: You made me think , in the exercise I am trying to solve, they have the following formulas :

Monthly interest rate = (Annual interest rate) / 12.0

Monthly unpaid balance = (Previous balance) - (Minimum monthly payment)

Updated balance each month = (Monthly unpaid balance) + (Monthly interest rate x Monthly unpaid balance)